# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 and Ihava try any i can searched answer

Tags: ios, swift

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayResp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AlipaySDK", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestAlipay.o
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayReq", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WXApiRequestHandler-E7499E6664382380.o
      objc-class-ref in OrderPaymentController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

1. I've tried to add libray to link binary with library
2. i've tried add headfile to complile source
3. pre issue is can't find PayResp because i delete the .a framework ,then add ,continue the present issue

that's error has waste all day time ,it's crazy me any help will thanks

Comment: It is a linker error, linker is looking for `PayResp` that you have deleted. Could you add it back ? Do you want assistance in adding it back ?

Comment: has add it back, that's my procedure find building phase->link binary with library  add the library.thanks , if you can assistance

Comment: http://docs.onemobilesdk.aol.com/ios-ad-sdk/adding-frameworks-xcode.html

Comment: i follow the step ,and still error , i turn the Build active architecture to NO will well,but another error  "Module 'xxxxx' has no member named 'yyy' ". if i turn to YES the Undefined symbols comback

Answer (score 1):

1. Repeat
2. Lack of dependency library
3. Modify “Other Linker Flags"
4. Support issues for file .a, armv7 and x86_64.

This problem can only be eliminated one by one

Comment: the 123 has complete ,the phase 4 how to do ?